# 'TFS build&release' Is there a way to change workitems' state included in the build when it occurs?

Tags: tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops, scrum, backlog

In tfs when automatic release occurs (each night) my team have to change their backlogitems asociated with this build to an state called 'ready for qa' next day, sometimes we forget it, if the build  mark those backlogitems as 'ready for qa' when it's success it would be great. Is there a way to configure the automatic release to do that?

Comment: What's the result after trying with Update Work Item task?

Answer (score 1):

I don't believe there is any native way to do this, but the following extension [Update Work Item](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=bool.update-work-item) in the VSTS marketplace should work for you.

After installing the extension, you will need to add a task to your Release Definition and configure it to suit your needs. Be sure to enable the "Allow Scripts to Access OAuth Token" setting in your release.

*Note: there are some nuances in configuring this task to be sure to read all of the 'help' icons during initial configuration*

[image: Release Configuration]

Answer (score 0):

Personally, I found using TFS Rest API as a good way of updating Work items. The Work items update TFS API is quite simple and easy to use

https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/wit/updates

The advantage of using it over build task is that you can run and test it locally and is easier to update and maintain